# I want to write the quaternion $q=2+i+j-5k$ in the form $r+lc$

Tags: quaternions

I want to write the quaternion $q=2+i+j-5k$ in the form $r+lc$, where $r,~c (\neq 0)$ are real numbers and $l^2=-1$.

We have the following relation $i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$ and $ij=k,\ jk=i,\ ki=j$.

I can't apply these or otherwise.

I think $l$ with $l^2=-1$ is the key point. This is another quaternion unit and we need to construct it.

Any help

Comment: Hint: $ij+ji = jk+kj = ki+ik = 0$, so $(i + j - 5k)^2 = ?$

Comment: @achillehui,thanks it is $-27$